# Apache Giraph - Cannot run in split master / worker mode since there is only 1 task at a time

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, giraph

I ran Giraph 1.0.0 with hadoop 2.2.0 using the PageRank Benchmark example [here](https://github.com/aching/Giraph/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).

Suddenly I got this error result:

> Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   checkLocalJobRunnerConfiguration: When using LocalJobRunner, must have
>   only one worker since only 1 task at a time!  at
>   org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphJob.checkLocalJobRunnerConfiguration(GiraphJob.java:151)
>     at org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphJob.run(GiraphJob.java:225)  at
>   org.apache.giraph.benchmark.GiraphBenchmark.run(GiraphBenchmark.java:90)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)     at
>   org.apache.giraph.benchmark.PageRankBenchmark.main(PageRankBenchmark.java:71)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

When I changed the number of workers to 1, I got:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   checkLocalJobRunnerConfiguration: When using LocalJobRunner, you
>   cannot run in split master / worker mode since there is only 1 task at
>   a time! at
>   org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphJob.checkLocalJobRunnerConfiguration(GiraphJob.java:157)
>     at org.apache.giraph.job.GiraphJob.run(GiraphJob.java:225)  at
>   org.apache.giraph.benchmark.GiraphBenchmark.run(GiraphBenchmark.java:90)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)     at
>   org.apache.giraph.benchmark.PageRankBenchmark.main(PageRankBenchmark.java:71)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

Any solutions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi I assume you are not running on a cluster? If I run in our demo VMs I get the same error.

You can disable the split master worker behaviour in giraph-site.xml

```
giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false
```

If you just want to disable this during a one-shot exeuction you can also pass it as a command-line parameter to your program.

```
-ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false
```

For instance I run a demo for my Big Data lecture like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

yarn jar /root/giraph-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar org.apache.giraph.GiraphRunner at.jku.tk.steinbauer.bigdata.giraph.MaxInDegreeComputation -vif org.apache.giraph.io.formats.JsonLongDoubleFloatDoubleVertexInputFormat -vip /user/hue/graph/tinygraph.txt -of org.apache.giraph.io.formats.IdWithValueTextOutputFormat  -op /user/hue/graph/degree -w 1 -ca giraph.SplitMasterWorker=false
```